# Converting msg files to HTML

Tags: html, vbscript, msg

I'm trying to convert msg files to HTML files without third party programs.   Thus far I have a VBscript I found in another question on this site.

```vb
Dim objshell, BaseName, outlookapp, emailPath
Set objshell = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
emailPath = "C:\Path\test.msg"
Set email = outlookapp.CreateItemFromTemplate(emailPath)

BaseName = objshell.GetBaseName(emailPath)
email.SaveAs objshell.GetParentFolderName(emailPath) & "\" & BaseName & ".html", 5
```

However, running this I get the error

> Action cancelled

Anyone able to tell me what is wrong?
Everywhere I look it seems like this script should work.

Comment: You set `emailPath` after you use it to instantiate `email` surely you want to set `emailPath = "C:\Path\test.msg"` before you do `Set email = outlookapp.CreateItemFromTemplate(emailPath)`?

Comment: Hm ok. I swaped the rowes of emailpath = "c:\" and "set email = .... " now. It now gives me a different error msg. "Action cancelled"  And it is now on row 8, (instead of the previous row 4).

Comment: It works for me. How you actually execute the script? Just double click on the vbs file? If you are using a 64-bit OS and a 32-Bit Outlook Application, you may want to execute that from command prompt with %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe and take note about any error reported

Comment: I've tried it, and done it through command prompt. The error message I get is:
(8, 1) (null): Action cancelled 
Well, it says that in my native language, but I'm guessing action cancelled is correctly translated.


However, that means nothing is wrong with the code, if it works for you. I guess I have to figure out why it wont execute properly.

Is it possible that I have to be logged in as administrator?

Comment: @TrueTom depends on the path but you may not have the correct permissions for the folder where you are trying to create the file, but wouldn't usually expect `Action Cancelled` error here.

Comment: I do have permissions to the folder so I doubt that is the issue.